# Angular ui grid does not show content unless browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs 1.5.0 with angular ui grid 3.1.1. 
When I assign gridOptions (passed to the grid directive) object in controller body like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
      data: [{"mock2": 1, "mock1": 2}, {"mock2": 10, "mock1": 22} ]
    };
```

HTML:

```
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

It displays the table as expected. But when I try to change data inside $scope.on:

```
$scope.$on('update', function (event, passedFromBroadcast) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data= [{"mock2": "set", "mock1": "inside"}, {"mock2": "$scope", "mock1": "on"} ] ;
    });
```

It renders only frame of the table, when including pagination it will also render pagination related controls - but not the content itself. 
Content (the rows and column headers) appear only after I resize my browser window.

1. **Why doesn't angular-ui grid update table content when the data changes inside $scope.on?**
2. **How can I manually update the angular ui grid table?**
   Things I already tried:

   ```
   $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize(); // Does not work
   $scope.gridApi.core.refresh(); // Does not work
   $timeout(function(){$scope.gridOptions.data= [{"mock2": "set", "mock1": "inside"}, {"mock2": "$scope", "mock1": "on"} ] ;}) // Does not work
   ```

Comment: Hese is the [example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data) of swap data, and the resolved [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1302).Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi Yin, thanks for the links. The issue was just about missing CSS width and height attributes. There was also additional issue - see accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a two issues with this code, but the reason for the table contents showing only after browser window resize is lack of css class defining width and height, basic (working) example:

```
    .grid {
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
     }
```

and in HTML:

```
    <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

The Other issue (mentioned by other people in this thread:

- assigning gridOption fields (data but also **columnDefs**) must be done inside $timeout, additionally both data and columnDefs need to be cleared before that. Otherwise it change might not become visible and table contents and headers will remain unchanged (known bug in ui-grid as @maurycy mentioned)

Answer (score 3):

It's a known bug when the gridOptions.data length doesn't change after update, proposed solution is to clear data and with use of $timeout refresh it

```
$scope.$on('update', function (event, passedFromBroadcast) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = null
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.data = [{"mock2": "set", "mock1": "inside"}, {"mock2": "$scope", "mock1": "on"} ] ;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I am afraid to does not solve it, I still need to resize the browser window to make the table appear.

Comment: did you used the angular `$timeout`?

Comment: I used angular $timeout. I have found out where the issue was - I lacked CSS class specifying width and height ... this apparently led to this refresh issue. $timeout thing was most likely another issue, but not the one directly causing table not to display at all.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the window resize handler on `$interval` has worked for me in the past inside the `gridOptions.onRegisterApi` method:

```
var gridResizeHandlerInterval; 

$scope.gridOptions = {
  ..., // etc.
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    ctrl.gridApi = gridApi;

    gridResizeHandlerInterval = $interval( function() {
      $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();
    }, 10, 500); 
  }
};
```

And then make sure you tidy up and cancel the interval when your controller gets destroyed:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $interval.cancel(gridResizeHandlerInterval);
});
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks! Even though it does not solve this particular problem - it was still very helpful. It is important to use gridApi.core.handleWindowResize(); in the next digest after any update to width, columnDefs or data. timeout can be used for that - interval will also work but it is more than enough, one call to gridApi.core.handleWindowResize(); is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
$scope.$on('update', function (event, passedFromBroadcast) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data.length = 0;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.data = [{"mock2": "set", "mock1": "inside"}, {"mock2": "$scope", "mock1": "on"} ] ;
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but it also does not change anything - it still renders only after manual browser resize.