# ui-grid 3.1.1 render content of table randomly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid in version 3.1.1
Facing the problem with rendering table. 
Not always but randomly table rendered without content after refreshing page data appears.
I tried set auto resize, refreshing data using $timeout ([Angular ui grid does not show content unless browser window is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485045/angular-ui-grid-does-not-show-content-unless-browser-window-is-resized?rq=1)) or increasing virtualizationThreshold.
Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and realized you must not change the reference to the data array. Basically you cannot assign grid data in a following way when they're loaded:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = [ your data ];
```

but rather do this instead:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.length = 0;
[your_data].forEach(d => $scope.gridOptions.data.push(a));
```